# Pandas: read_table remove comment lines with '##' but not '#<string>'?

Tags: python, pandas

I have some large tab separated data sets that have long commented sections, followed by the table header, formatted like this:

```
##FORMAT=<ID=AMQ,Number=.,Type=Integer,Description="Average mapping quality for each allele present in the genotype">
##FORMAT=<ID=SS,Number=1,Type=Integer,Description="Variant status relative to non-adjacent Normal, 0=wildtype,1=germline,2=somatic,3=LOH,4=unknown">
##FORMAT=<ID=SSC,Number=1,Type=Integer,Description="Somatic Score">
#CHROM  POS ID  REF ALT QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT  NORMAL  TUMOR
chr1    2985885 .   c   G   .   .   .   GT:IGT:DP:DP4:BCOUNT:GQ:JGQ:VAQ:BQ:MQ:AMQ:SS:SSC    0/0:0/0:202:36,166,0,0:0,202,0,0:255:225:0:36:60:60:0:. 0/1:0/1:321:29,108,37,147:0,137,184,0:228:225:228:36,36:60:60,60:2:225
chr1    3312963 .   C   T   .   .   .   GT:IGT:DP:DP4:BCOUNT:GQ:JGQ:VAQ:BQ:MQ:AMQ:SS:SSC    0/1:0/1:80:36,1,43,0:0,37,0,43:80:195:80:36,31:60:60,60:1:. 0/0:0/0:143:138,5,0,0:0,143,0,0:255:195:255:36:60:60:3:57
```

Everything that starts with `##` is a comment that needs to be stripped out, but I need to keep the header that starts with `#CHROM`. Is there any way to do this? The only options I am seeing for Pandas `read_table` allow only a single character for the comment string, and I do not see options for regular expressions.

The code I am using is this:

```
SS_txt_df = pd.read_table(SS_txt_file,sep='\t',comment='#')
```

This removes all lines that start with `#`, including the header I want to keep

EDIT: For clarification, the header region starting with `##` is of variable length. In bash this would simply be `grep -Ev '^##'`.

Comment: look up csv.reader examples, readline, skip lines starting with "##", build list then convert into dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can easily calculate the number of header lines, that must be skipped when reading your CSV file:

```
fn =  '/path/to/file.csv'

skip_rows = 0
with open(fn, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('##'):
            skip_rows += 1
        else:
            break

df = pd.read_table(fn, sep='\t', skiprows=skip_rows)
```

The first part will read only the header lines - so it should be very fast

Answer (score 1):

use `skiprows` as a workaround:

```
SS_txt_df = pd.read_table(SS_txt_file,sep='\t',skiprows=3)
df
Out[13]: 
  #CHROM  POS ID  REF ALT QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT  NORMAL  TUMOR
0  chr1    2985885 .   c   G   .   .   .   GT:IGT...                   
1  chr1    3312963 .   C   T   .   .   .   GT:IGT...
```

then rename your first column to remove #.
 **Update:**
As you said your `##` varies so, I know this is not a feasible solution but you can drop all rows starting with `#` and then pass the column headers as `list`as your columns don't change:

```
name=['CHROM','POS','ID','REF','ALT','QUAL','FILTER','INFO' ,'FORMAT','NORMAL','TUMOR']

df=pd.read_table(SS_txt_file,sep='\t',comment='#',names=name)
df
Out[34]:
   CHROM  POS ID  REF ALT QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT  NORMAL  TUMOR
    0  chr1    2985885 .   c   G   .   .   .   GT:IGT...                   
    1  chr1    3312963 .   C   T   .   .   .   GT:IGT...
```

Comment: Sorry I only posted a snippet of the dataset; the header I am removing which starts with `##` is much longer and of variable length.

Comment: Does number of columns vary?

Comment: In this case, no. Only the number of rows.